# How to grab numbers in glVertex3f?

Tags: java, lwjgl, vbo

Recently, I've been making a game.

I do not want to try to use VAOs and VBOs because I cannot wrap my head around that stuff.

But, in order to use custom shaders, I need an arraylist of things to add to a VBO.

So I want to grab each and every float in the `glVertex3f` in this line of code:

```
public void drawCube() {
    
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES);
    
    // GL11.glColor3f(toRatio(155), toRatio(202), toRatio(222));
    
    //FRONT QUAD
    
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x,  10 * x, 10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, 10 * x, 10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x, -10 * x, 10 * x);        
    
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x, -10 * x, 10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, 10 *x, 10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, -10 * x, 10 * x);
    
    //BACK QUAD
    
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x,  10 * x, -10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, 10 * x, -10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x, -10 * x, -10 * x);        
    
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x, -10 * x, -10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, 10 *x, -10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, -10 * x, -10 * x);
    
    //LEFT QUAD
    
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x, 10 * x, -10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x, 10 * x, 10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x, -10 * x, -10 * x);
    
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x, -10 * x, -10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x, 10 * x, 10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x, -10 * x, 10 * x);
    
    //RIGHT QUAD
    
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, 10 * x, 10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, 10 * x, -10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, -10 * x, 10 * x);
    
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, -10 * x, 10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, 10 * x, -10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, -10 * x, -10 * x);
    
    //TOP QUAD
    
    //debugColor();
    
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x,  10 * x, -10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x,  10 * x, -10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x,  10 * x, 10 * x);
    
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x, 10 * x, 10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, 10 * x, -10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, 10 * x, 10 * x);
    
    //BOTTOM QUAD
    
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x,  -10 * x, -10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x,  -10 * x, -10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x,  -10 * x, 10 * x);
    
    GL11.glVertex3f(-10 * x, -10 * x, 10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, -10 * x, -10 * x);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10 * x, -10 * x, 10 * x);
    
    
    GL11.glEnd();
    
}
```

Is it possible to do that? How do I grab these floats? I know how to put them into an arraylist but I just need to floats first...

Comment: You don't need a VBO to use shaders, you can use shaders with glBegin/glEnd just fine.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus Yes, but I want to use a custom shader using vertex and fragment files, so how would I do that?

Comment: Like shadow mapping and normals calculation and lighting up certain faces
Like the cube that I'm rendering just stays white even though the gl_FragColor and vec3 color is darker than pure white. The outColor has an absolute value function from thebookofshaders.com

Comment: It sounds like you want a full-on tutorial on shaders. That's more than can be provided in a single question.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus No, I dont want a full tutorial on shaders, I just want to be able to use these vertex and fragment shaders properly because even though I'm animating the color, the rendered cube still stays white. :/

Comment: You should edit your question to be specific about what your actual problem is, then - that will make it easier for people to give you answers that are actually helpful.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus it works now, but uniforms aren't updating in the shader....